# Pandas replace is replacing my column values with something else

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I have a pandas dataframe which has a column called *income*. It has a value "<-50k". I want to replace it with 0. This is the code I have written

```
print(data["income"].head())
data["income"] = data.replace({"income": {"<=50K": 0}})
print(data["income"].head())
```

This is the result I am getting.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the initial blank spaces.I think you need:

```
data["income"] = data["income"].str.replace('\s+<=50K', '0')
#check
#data.loc[0, "income"]
```

otherwise there will still be blank spaces

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data["income"] = data["income"].str.replace("<=50K", "0")
print(data)

  income
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have white space in the column so add `regex=True`

```
data["income"] = data.replace({"income": {"<=50K": 0}},regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.replace({"income": {"<=50K": 0}}, inplace=True)
```